# Laying Out 'ggplot2' Plots in R With Complicated, Offset Layout Matrices

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following layout of plots made with `base` functions.

```
Layout_Matrix <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0), nrow = 2, byrow =  TRUE)
layout(Layout_Matrix)
plot(0, main = 'Plot 1')
plot(0, main = 'Plot 2')
plot(0, main = 'Plot 3')
```

[image]

Can I reproduce something similar with `ggplot2` plots? I want to make sure each plot is exactly the same size. The `wrap_plots()` function from the `patchwork` package nearly gets me there, but the plots don't end up being all the same size. Also, I know I could do something like the code below, but I want to find a neat, efficient way to handle any situation (such as four rows each with five plots and then a final row with two plots) without having to copy and paste code. Thanks!

```
Plot_1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()
Plot_2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()
Plot_3 <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()
(Plot_1 | Plot_2) / (patchwork::plot_spacer() + Plot_3 + patchwork::plot_spacer() + patchwork::plot_layout(widths = c(1, 2, 1)))
```

[image]